# Converting comma to point

Tags: matlab

I have a text file like this column wise:

```
0,472412
0,455627
0,439148
0,421753
...
0,116577
0,086670
0,057373
0,027161
```

How can I convert the comma into dot in matlab?

Answer (score 4):

[This post](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/241937) on Matlabs site suggests:

```
function comma2point_overwrite( filespec )
% replaces all occurences of comma (",") with point (".") in a text-file.
% Note that the file is overwritten, which is the price for high speed.
    file = memmapfile( filespec, 'writable', true );
    comma = uint8(',');
    point = uint8('.');
    file.Data( transpose( file.Data==comma) ) = point;
    delete(file)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

... or you could do this:

```
wholefile = fileread('yourfile.txt')       % read in entire file
newfiledata = strrep(wholefile,',','.')    % replace commas with full stops
fileid = fopen('yourfile.txt','w')         % open file to write
fprintf(fileid,'%s',newfiledata)           % print to file
fclose(fid2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option, (since you want to open the file into matlab's workspace) is to:

- load the file using

  ```
   a=load('filename.txt');
  ```

Because the comma is a default delimiter, you'll get a 2xN matrix, such as:

```
a =

       0      472412
       0      455627
       0      439148
       0      421753
```

- Find the significant # of digits to get the proper decimal point position:

  ```
   d = 10.^(1+floor(log10(abs(a(:,2)))));
  ```
- then:

  ```
   v=a(:,2)./d
  ```

will yield the vector you wanted. Now you can save it back to file, or do whatever...

Answer (score 1):

> > a='0,00445'

**a = 0,00445**

> > b=strrep(a,',','.')

**b = 0.00445**